# How to do: use MPMoviePlayerController to play a remote video that must request from proxy server

Tags: iphone, proxy, mpmovieplayercontroller

Hi everyone
I'm debugging an iphone app in iphone simulator and need to do a job described as title
there is a socks proxy in mac's system network setting
 
the proxy works fine when using NSMutableURLRequest, but can not works with MPMoviePlayerController
please help, thanks.